# Why do I receive attribute error for replacing a cells content in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I tried

```
df3.at[294,'Initial Effective Date'].str.replace("5/26/19 and 8/2/20","8/2/20")
```

My dataframe(df3) has multiple columns and 300 rows of data. I have a column called initial eff date
I just want to replace a cell at row 294 as it as above. but I get an error saying
attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df3.at[294,'Initial Effective Date'] = "8/2/20"
```

`.str.replace()` method is for Series and you get only one cell (String) with `.at()`